# Composer Json Validation Error for regex pattern ^[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*/[a-z0-9](([_.]?|-{0,2})[a-z0-9]+)*$

Tags: json, composer-php

so i tried to install composer and laravel into Phpstorm, but right now there seems to be a problem installing the `composer.json` file in php. `PHP` version is `7.4.8`. The error code is as shown below.

```
   "./composer.json" does not match the expected JSON schema:
    - name : Does not match the regex pattern ^[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*/[a-z0-9](([_.]?|-{0,2})[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

I tried to look it up for help but it didnt get me far enough, so I was wondering if anyone could help me out with this problem.

this is how my composer.json looked like.

```
{
  "name": "vendor_name/PhpProjec",
  "description": "description",
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "***",
      "email": "email@example.com"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "v2.7.0"
  }
```

Comment: And what is actual name of your package (I'm assuming that `vendor_name/PhpProjec` is only placeholder used in question)?

Comment: sorry what do you mean by package? @rob006

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you probably using Composer v2? When I use the given JSON in my local environment using Composer v1, it tells me:

> Deprecation warning: Your package name vendor_name/PhpProjec is invalid, it should not contain uppercase characters. We suggest using vendor_name/php-projec instead. Make sure you fix this as Composer 2.0 will error.

The error message you've provided does not occur on my system. If you are still facing problems after using another package name, please share more details

Comment: I'm currently using composer ver1.10.9.

Answer (score 25):

The problem is in the **"name"** property

```
- name : Does not match the regex pattern ^[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*/[a-z0-9](([_.]?|-{0,2})[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

Change the "name" property accordingly **"vendor-name/project-name"**

eg: `"name": "nismi/my-php-project"`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as the selected answer doesn't really say why it is happening and the solution given is not really a solution. The question was about the error in the name property

Answer (score 4):

composer is case sensitive from v1.9 onwards...
so change "PhpProject" to "phpproject"

```
   {
  "name": "vendor_name/phpproject",
  "description": "description",
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "***",
      "email": "email@example.com"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "v2.7.0"
  }
```

Comment: In my case I was specifying name as `"name": "projectname"`, instead it had to be in the format `"name": "vendorname/projectname"`

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix go to `composer.json` file find where is capitalizised e.g Izupay/PayMent to izupay/payment this will fix the error.

```json
{
  "name": "IzuPay/PayMent",
  "description": "description",
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "***",
      "email": "email@example.com"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "v2.7.0"
  }
```

Working answer is:

```json
{
  "name": "izupay/payment",
  "description": "description",
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "***",
      "email": "email@example.com"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "v2.7.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This most likely has to do with the version of Composer you're using.

Before Composer version 2.0, a name could contain *any character*, including white spaces.

However, from version 2.0 upwards:

- the name can consists of words separated by -, . or _.
- the complete name should match ^a-z0-9*/a-z0-9*$.
- the name must be **lowercased** (so instead of `vendor_name/PhpProjec`, it would be `vendor_name/phpprojec`